# Define parameter of variable length after specific string, but before the next line

Tags: python, split, python-3.6

I've done my due diligence trying to find an answer to this, but haven't had any luck.

Example string:

```
test = 'CurrentEmail:EMAIL@gmail.com\n' \
       'CurrentTime:TIME\n' \
       'CurrentLocation:LOCATION'
```

What I am trying to do is define each one of those parameters separately as in:

```
CurrentEmail = 'EMAIL@gmail.com', CurrentTime = 'TIME', CurrentLocation = 'LOCATION'.
```

So somehow extracting between the `:` and the next line, `\n` all from that same test string.

Thank you very much for your help!

EDIT:
I was able to use the following.

```
new_test = test.splitlines()
for lines in new_test:
if 'CurrentEmail:' in lines:
    CurrentEmail = lines.replace('CurrentEmail:', '')
elif 'CurrentTime' in lines:
    CurrentTime = lines.replace('CurrentTime:', '')
elif 'CurrentLocation:' in lines:
    CurrentLocation = lines.replace('CurrentLocation:', '')
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Use a dictionary: `dict(map(lambda x: x.split(':'), test.splitlines()))`.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why.